# Problem with setting a environment variable in Windows

Tags: windows, hadoop, environment-variables

I am trying to setup a simple Hadoop Mapreduce example on my laptop.
I installed everything as explained here: https://gist.github.com/vorpal56/5e2b67b6be3a827b85ac82a63a5b3b2e

The thing is when I try to compile my code using "javac -classpath ..." command, I got some errors, the first one being:

```
src\WordCountMapper.java:5: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
```

I checked and double checked and my intellij is correctly detecting hadoop libraries I already added (when I change slightly the import, the line becomes red).

I tried googling and using ChatGPT, the latter suggested to check HADOOP_HOME env variable, which I did and it is correctly set. However when I tried "echo $HADOOP_HOME$" both on cmd and Powershell (I am on windows 10), I get $HADOOP_HOME$, and a similar thing when I try "echo $env:HADOOP_HOME".

I reset both cmd terminal and Powershell, restarted intellij, rebuilt project in intellij, restarted my laptop etc, nothing solves the issue.

Comment: Check with https://www.rapidee.com/en/about that the env variable is set correctly. Fix it if it doesn't point to a directory. Reboot or logout/login.

Comment: 1) Java 8 is end of life. Those instructions shouldn't be followed exactly 2) Windows doesn't use dollar sign for interpolation of env vars in CMD... It uses percent signs. Otherwise, you need to show your control panel window where you've set the value. 3) Installing Hadoop in WSL2 will run much better